# BlogEngine.net Comments Remove Email Requirement

Tags: blogengine.net

I can't see the point of making an email address mandatory for people posting comments when they can make up a dummy address. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The `/User controls/CommentView.ascx` user control is responsible for validating comments.  If you remove the following line it will no longer be required.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="<%$Resources:labels, required %>" Display="dynamic" ValidationGroup="AddComment" />
```

I would recommend you verify with whatever backend you are using that leaving that value out will not break any other functionality.  One thing I know relies on the email address is the [gravatar](http://gravatar.com) code so you should probably check it as well.

Comment: Thanks, Lee, that's exactly what I wanted, just had to remove the asterisk for 'required' from the Email label. Not bothered about effect on Gravatar as I'm not using that either.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting and informative post. Good job! keep it up, hope to read your other updates. Thanks for this nice sharing
[taxi in doha](http://taxiindoha.com)
[taxi in doha qatar](http://taxiindoha.com)

Comment: This should be in comment.